# Have multiple index with same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 queries like this

```
select * 
from dbo.employee 
where employee.name = 'lucas' 
  and employee.age = 36 
  and employee.address = 'street 6'
```

and a second query like this

```
select * 
from dbo.employee 
where employee.name = 'lucas' 
  and employee.address = 'street 6'
```

I created an index with multiple columns like this

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_EMPLOYEE] 
ON dbo.employee (name, age, address)
```

This index work for the first query and performance is fast, but the second query took longer.

How can I reproduce this issue?

I expected create multiple index with same column will improve a second query but there is no different same took a longer

Comment: A "compound" index (on several columns) can **only ever** be used if the **n left-most columns** of the index are being used in your query. In your second query, you only use `name` in your `WHERE` clause - so that index *could be used* to limit the search scope by name - but only by name. So the search scope (the number of rows to search) will be significantly bigger than in your first query where you use **all three** columns of the index and thus have a much smaller search scope to look at

Comment: If you had your index on `(name, address, age)` , SQL Server might be able to use it for the second query as well

Comment: It's extremely important order of cols from key of index. If this cols are (a, b, c) this is totally different than (a, c, b), in this case create the index on (name, address) or  (address, name)

Answer (score 0):

Use such an index:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_EMPLOYEE] 
ON dbo.employee (name, address, age)
```

Note the order of columns and the fact that name + address covers the `WHERE` clause of the second query (therefore will make it *seekable*, that is fast), and that this index is usable in the first query as well.

It would work equally well if order of columns was `(address, name, age)`. For those queries, select the one from those two that has the greatest amount of unique values (check it with `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT address) FROM dbo.employee` or try to predict if you don't have the data yet).

You may consider removing the "age" column from the index if there are not many people with the same name at the same address in the worst case. It will seek to the first name + address, and then *range scan* through all the 'lucas'es on 'street 6' to find if any of them matches the age. If data model allows that, it'd be a reasonable change. However "age" column is probably narrow, so the savings won't be huge, in contrast to "address" column which contains more data (but needs to be first or second in order for those queries to be seekable).